# Rename [lego-batman-2] to [lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I'd like to propose renaming the tag for Lego Batman 2: DC Super Heroes from [lego-batman-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-batman-2) to [lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Created [lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-batman-2-dc-super-heroes) and made former tag a synonym.